# Protractor Cucumber Step Defintions can't be found

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I am trying to setup Protractor with Cucumber however I cannot seem to get the step definition file to be recognised.

At present am using:

**cucumber": "^3.2.1"**

**protractor-cucumber": "^0.1.8"**

**protractor-cucumber-framework": "^4.1.1"**

The project is running on windows and is setup as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Project Setup]

I have my step cumcumberOpts set like this:

```
cucumberOpts: {
require: 'features/step_definitions/stepDefinitions.js',
tags: false,
profile: false,
'no-source': true
}
```

and the specs are defined as:

```
specs: [
'features/*.feature'
],
```

However the step definitions are not found.
The step file contains:

```
var steps = function() {
this.Given(/^I go to "([^"]*)"$/, function (callback) {
browser
.get("https://localhost:4200")
.then(callback);
});   

};
module.exports = steps;
```

I can't see anything that is obviously wrong.

Comment: can you add your step definition, could be a matching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) change cucumberOpts.require as below:

```
cucumberOpts: {
  require: [
    'features/step_definitions/stepDefinitions.js'
  ]
```

2) since Cucumber 2, the code pattern of step definition is changed, your code pattern is suitable for Cucumber 1, Change your step defintion as below:

```
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function ({Given, When, Then}) {

    Given(/^Expand Accounts panel$/, function () {
        //;
    });

    When(/^Expand Accounts panel$/, function () {
        //;
    });

    Then(/^Expand Accounts panel$/, function () {
        //;
    });

});
```

**Note:** No need module.exports or exports.xxx in step defintion file.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try - I did see a large number of tutorials and all were different, so I suspected that something had changed.

Comment: many thanks again - your changes worked a treat.  Have they changed how the browser interaction works? Admitadly I was using standard protractor and used browser.get(url) however this isn't working with cucumber?

Comment: Firstly open your url in browser manually, if the page can open, one possbile reason is the webriver not compatible with your browser, or something wrong in your protractor conf file, please give the entier conf file

Comment: Suspect it will be the config file, if I use "normal" protractor then I can use the browser fine, it is going to be something around cucumber which is causing the issue..

Comment: `exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
        
    framework: 'custom',
    
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'firefox'
    },
  
    // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
    specs: [
      'features/*.feature'
    ],
  
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  
    cucumberOpts: {
      require: [
        'features/step_definitions/stepDefinitions.js'
      ]

    },

  };`

Comment: forgot to tag you

Comment: no error stack,  I can see the browser launching but nothing ever appears in the window.  I changed my step defintion to try and add a 10 second timer, but this also doesn't work.

Comment: step definition: `the step definition is:  `var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

defineSupportCode(function ({Given, When, Then}) {
  Given(/^I go to "([^"]*)"$/, function (url, next) {
    //browser.get(url).then(() => browser.sleep(1000));
    //browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
   browser.get(url);
    browser.sleep(10000).then(function() {
      console.log('waited 10 seconds');
    });

    next();
  });

});`

Comment: Tell me the verions of your Chrome and a mail address, I will send a minimize workable project with you used dependency verions to you.

Comment: chrome version is 63, however my script was starting firefox (version 57) - joseph dot adams at blueyonder dot co uk is the email